# cannot receive POST values in php submitted through select onChange

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, select

Well i'm submitting form through `onChange` of select

```
<form name="selForm" id="selForm" type="POST>
       <select name="sel_status" id="sel_status">
          <option value="one">one</option>
          <option value="two">two</option>
       </select>
</form>
```

My jQuery Code

```
$('#sel_status').change(function(){
    $('#selForm').submit();
});
```

And then i'm echoinging the value submitted in php

```
echo $_POST['sel_status'];
```

My network tab in Chrome showing 302 status

[image]

So how to submit the form through onChange of select and receive those values in php?

Comment: try to use `print_r($_POST);` or `print_r($_POST['sel_status']);` and check value is comming or not?

Comment: But where is `action` within `form` tag

Comment: method is also needed not type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form name="selForm" id="selForm" type="POST">
```

The `action` is missing and it's `method`, not `type`

Answer (score 1):

You've got an error in your HTML code.

First, there is a " missing (after POST) and this attribute is called method, not type. So the correct code should be:

```
<form name="selForm" id="selForm" method="post">
    <select name="sel_status" id="sel_status">
        <option value="one">one</option>
        <option value="two">two</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

If your PHP code is in an other file, you also have to set the `action="yourfile.php"` attribute

Answer (score 0):

Use $_POST['sel_status'];

You cannot use echo $_POST['selForm'];  "selForm" is name of the form.

Answer (score 0):

Add form `action="yourphpfile.php"` and change `method="POST"`.

Try:

```
echo $_POST['sel_status'];
```